# how to run a shell command every boot in CentOS 6.6?

Tags: centos, vmware

I want to use this command every boot

```
>/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

so I wrote it in `/etc/rc.local` but it didn't help , is ">" a problem ?

my purpose is to clear /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules

thank you very much

Comment: Why would you NEED to clear a file in /etc on EVERY boot anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried alternatives, like `cat /dev/null > /etc/...`?  Or added logging statements so that you can be sure the script is running?